# How can I create an Intel Atom x86_64 Android avd with command line

Tags: android, emulation, android-virtual-device

I am trying to automate the process of creating android emulators, installing and testing applications on them, and deleting them. I am able to create and launch an emulator from the UI.  But, when I runt the command below:

```
android create avd
```

I get the error:

```
Error: The parameters --target, --name must be defined for action 'create avd'
```

Not knowing what a target is I looked around and found that if I ran `android list targets` it would show me a list of the targets I have installed.  The target listed below is what I believe I need

```
id: 2 or "android-25"
 Name: Android 7.1.1
 Type: Platform
 API level: 25
 Revision: 1
 Skins: HVGA, QVGA, WQVGA400, WQVGA432, WSVGA, WVGA800 (default), WVGA854, WXGA720, WXGA800, WXGA800-7in
Tag/ABIs : android-tv/x86, google_apis/x86, google_apis/x86_64
```

So I modified my command to include the id of the target as well as adding a name to get

```
android create avd -n test2 -t 2
```

I get the error:

```
Error: Invalid --tag default for the selected target.
```

I have googled around and really can't find out what a tag is and how I know what tag applies to which target and I also see a lot of people defining abi's and don't know how to relate that to the correct target..

Is there anyone out there who knows how to create an AVD from command line!!

Comment: I'm just wondering why you would delete the environments.

Comment: I'm testing android apks that are known to be malicious/viruses.  So they frequently screw up the emulators.  I just want to creat a new one for every android apk I deploy to the device.

Answer (score 4):

I see you have the **tag** in the output for `android list targets`

```
Tag/ABIs : android-tv/x86, google_apis/x86, google_apis/x86_64
```

You probably have to choose on specific one like using `--tag 'android-tv/x86'` or the short form `-g 'android-tv/x86'`

You probably don't have a `default` target in your avaialble avd's.

Comment: I tried `$ android create avd --name 'test' --target 2 --tag 'google_apis/x86_64'` but got the error:
`Error: Invalid --tag google_apis/x86_64 for the selected target.`

Comment: Ah, man you just gotta use `--abi` instead of `--tag` I'll count your answer though thanks for the help!

Comment: to be clear, this works `android create avd --name 'test2' --target 'android-25' --abi 'google_apis/x86_64`

Comment: I ran into the same problem where it was spewing Error invalid tag and I messed around with the commands and found this to work:
`avdmanager create avd -n kitkat_x86 -k system-images;android-19;google_apis;x86 -g google_apis`